# How to remove all characters before colon in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

{'Smax38': 0.0, 'Smax39': 0.0, 'Geto': 2.048, 'Chi5ch': 0.0, 'Smax35': 5.048, 'Smax36': 6.347, 'Smax37': 0.0, 'Smax30': 0.0}

I want to remove all characters before colon in each item of list mentioned above.
Output must be written to txt file with only values seperated by comma or space like mentioned below

0.0, 0.0, 2.048, 0.0, 5.048, 6.347, 0.0, 0.0

Comment: are you sure that is a `list` and not a `dict`. You seem to referring it to as a `list`. You should probably check out the [docs for dict](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have a `dict`, so try:

```
d = {'Smax38': 0.0, 'Smax39': 0.0, 'Geto': 2.048, 'Chi5ch': 0.0, 'Smax35': 5.048, 'Smax36': 6.347, 'Smax37': 0.0, 'Smax30': 0.0}
res = ','.join(map(str, d.values()))
# 0.0,0.0,2.048,0.0,5.048,6.347,0.0,0.0
```

Note that the order of the values won't necessarily be in the order you declare the dictionary, since dictionaries are arbitrarily ordered. So you may wish to consider forcing some ordering based on the key...

Note that if it is genuinely a string, then you could parse it using `ast.parse`:

```
import ast

s = "{'Smax38': 0.0, 'Smax39': 0.0, 'Geto': 2.048, 'Chi5ch': 0.0, 'Smax35': 5.048, 'Smax36': 6.347, 'Smax37': 0.0, 'Smax30': 0.0}"
p = ast.parse(s)
res =','.join(str(node.n) for node in p.body[0].value.values)
# 0.0,0.0,2.048,0.0,5.048,6.347,0.0,0.0
```